# symfony redirect in a function

Tags: php, redirect, symfony, this

In my project I use the framework as Symfony2. I wanted to write a php function that redirect to a default page if a condition fails. so my function was like this.

```
public function validate($value){
    if($value==null){
        return  $this->redirect(
             $this->generateUrl('home_page', array("message"=>""))
        ); 
    }   
}
```

and I call the function like this.

```
$this->validate($value);
```

problem is redirect does not happens.
please guys, help me. I don't know why it is not redirecting.
Thanks

Comment: Does this function is in your controller?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd have to call it like this:

```
$response = $this->validate($value);

if ($response instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response) {
    return $response;
}
```

Instead of returning a response you could throw a custom redirect exception and write a listener which would create a redirect response.

Answer (score 1):

In order to redirect, the calling action should return a redirect response. Meaning, you should return `validate()`'s return.

```
return $this->validate($value);
```

Comment: You have to check what's returned. If validate() returns nothing you don't want to interrupt but continue executing your controller's code.

Comment: @Jakub Zalas ah yes, youre right. my bad. :$ I was too focused on why the code didn't redirect. +1 to you